# Sharepoint 2010 Workflow send email after list item creation

Tags: 2010, workflow, lookup-column, email

I'm creating a custom  workflow for my team in SharePoint 2010. When someone edits a list item and sets a value to "New" then a new item is created a different list. I would like to email the user and link to the newly created item's display form.

so: User modifies item in list A which starts work flow
item in list b is created

need: email user with link to display form for the new item in list b.

Everything is working fine except that I can't figure out what kind of lookup to use to put the link to the new item in the email. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you create a list item, there is a variable that will be tied to the ID of the new item. Whenever you create the email, you can create a hyperlink in the body that derives from the url of the default displayform and add the ID of the new item like this:

[image]

```
http://sharepoint/sites/sitecoll/lists/customlist/dispform.aspx?ID=[Variable:create]
```

Comment: thank you so much! I can't tell you how much time I have spent trying to figure this out!